# Set background of the div with set width to go across the whole screen

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with set max-width of 1200px. I want to set a background, however, I want the background to go all the way across the screen and ignore the width of the div. Is this possible using CSS?

```
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
```

I want to keep the content of the element to listen to the max-width property. It's just the background that I want to go all the way across.

**EDIT**

To people who think I didn't try to solve the problem in different ways. I did, and I got it working. However, my question is:

**Is it possible to set the `background-color` of the div that will ignore the size of the div and go across the whole screen? (outside of the div)** With no parent and inner containers and using pure CSS...

Comment: Just take one div with with:100% and the background and into that another div with the max-width and the content?

Comment: Why don't you just set the `width` on the `body`?

Comment: try use `min-width: 100%;`

Comment: If you really must use this div, you could use a ::before or ::after pseudo element on it, as long as it doesn't have its overflow hidden. I could not recommend that though; not KISS enough.

Comment: There was many attempts Rope :) I have created another div on top of this one and moved the bottom one on top of it using `top: xx` property, but this seems to be bringing problems. My precise question is, is there a way of setting the background colour of a div to ignore the max-width property and go outside of the div.

Comment: No, there is no way.

Comment: Then you need to review the purpose of the `top` property. It is not used to "order the layers" of the page on the z-axis.

Comment: I managed to do it by creating a parent and inner containers. But wanted to check if there is a way of achieving it the way mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a pseudo element that you make fixed and use inherit to get background of the container:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: But like I said in my comment, not recommended.

Comment: @MrLister and it's the only CSS solution

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help.

You can use this killer way.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    z-index: -1;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
max-width: 1200px
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BareFeet pay attention to this as it will break if you add `position:relative` to container

Answer (score -1):

This goes against the structure of the HTML document.

> While you can technically "hack" your way into making this happen, you
>   should simply use proper structure instead

All child nodes are contained within their parent element.
If you want your element to not be bound to its parent, then simply place it outside of it.

```css
#inside { 
  width: 80%;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%; /* redundant, but for illustration purposes */
}

 body > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="inside">
    <div class="fullwidth">
      I'll always be 100% of my parent's width
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="fullwidth">
    My parent is body (which is 100%), so I'll be 100% of body as well!
  </div>
</body>
```

You're essentially creating a problem that's not there.
Instead of trying to find a way to break the flow of a document, you should **use proper HTML document structure instead**

---

**Note:** Obviously, you can create a `.wrapper` that will server as a 100% width background for your content, that will be 80% or something. This is the common convention afterall.

Comment: I'm just looking for different solutions and see what people come up with. I know this can be achieved different way, however, I was curious if it was possible this way. Thanks for your time and will to help me :)